# Max Memory Allocation on 32 bit JDK

Tags: java, memory, jboss

I am getting out of memory errors on a jboss webapp and have tweaked memory settings and when values seem larger than 1024 on specific settings I get a java run time error could not allocate memory. Does anyone know what the max values I can use below on a 32bit jdk?

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

Comment: Congratulations! You asked the 333111st java question! :P On a more related note, a Google search for your question title returned https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2469773&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks, but how is asking the 333111st java question an achievement?

Comment: I don't know, I just randomly noticed :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate more than 1GB for heap on 32-bit JDK (sounds like something that depends on the JVM implementation, but according to Google it's around 1.5GB).

You probably don't have enough available memory on your server. Free up some memory and have a try.